# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 and occasion EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python newbie and I'm trying to create and define a set of functions that compute the median mode and mean of a set of numbers in a list. I'm also trying to include a main function that tests all 3 functions with a given list. I've been getting error after error for the last 3 days and I can't find any helpful solutions on google. my latest error is

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10.
```

What am I doing wrong? And are there any other errors that I may be overlooking in my script?

```
"""
File: stats.py
"""
#Prints median of a set of numbers in a list
numList = int(input("Enter a list of numbers"))

def median(list):
    numList = []
numList.sort()
middle = len(numList)//2
if len(numList) % 2 == 1:
    print(numList[middle])
print((numList[middle] + numList[middle - 1])/2)
if numList == []:
    print (0)

#Prints mode of a set of numbers in a list
def mode(list):
    numList = []
    for repeat in numList:
        number = nums.get(repeat,none)
    if number == none:
        nums[repeat] = 1
        nums[repeat] = number + 1
        theMaximum = max(nums.values())
        for repeat in nums:
            if nums[repeat] == theMaximum:
                print (repeat)
                if numList == []:
                    print (0)

#Prints average of a set of numbers in a list
def mean(list):
    sum = 0
    for number in numList:
        sum += number
        print (sum)/len(numList)
        if numList == []:
            print (0)

#The main function for this script
def main():
    numList = [2,6,18,42,90,18,9,15,26,18,82]
    result = mean[2,6,18,42,90,18,9,15,26,18,82]
    print("The mean of" , [2,6,18,42,90,18,9,15,26,18,82], "is", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
numList = int(input("Enter a list of numbers"))
```

You input a **list** if numbers. Then you use the `int()` method to try to convert this **list** to one integer.

That obviously fails. "1,2,3,4,5" is not an integer, it's five integers, and they need to be converted separately.

There are various ways you can do this, `.split(',')` is one way, using a look and asking for the integers one by one is another.

Comment: there are more errors. after that fix it should not run due to `result = mean[2,6,18,42,90,18,9,15,26,18,82]`

Comment: @joaquin: Oh sure there are more errors, but one thing at a time. I'm not going to write his code for him, he won't learn that way. :-) His problem is that he wrote the code without testing any of it, and it doesn't work. Code should be written line by line.